# Beginner iOS app data upload to website

Tags: ios, web-services, cocoa-touch

First off I'm new to iOS and I'm at the early stages of development but would like to start in the correct direction, I did some basic iOS tutorials and have done html/c++ development. We have two members making this app, he will be in charge of UI and local data storage while I need to upload data from iOS to website. There will be a local database logging rapidly, there is two types of uploading I would like to do.

1. A "live stream" of data which updates the text on the website every second or so.
2. Once this session of data logging is complete it will have a upload button to have the entire database uploaded.

I'm looking for which methods, database, and apis I should be using. I have been looking around and people use different API's and I'm not sure what best applies to my app. If you have links to tutorials that would also be appreciated. From looking around it looks like I should use sql(on phone and web server), php, and the post. Thanks.

Comment: "I'm new to iOS" - in this case, you probably haven't yet read/heard my 1st rule for iOS-related SO questions: you are most likely misusing the Xcode tag. Xcode is not needed for iOS development, and the tag should not be used for general iOS-related programming questions. Please read the tag's tag wiki for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend going with one of Platform As A Service providers (PAAS) they provide the server infrastructure and the iOS client APIs. There are many out there to choose between. e.g. [Stackmob](http://www.stackmob.com), [Parse](http://www.parse.com), [Kinvey](http://www.kinvey.com), but there are a number of others. All offer free services until you get a significant volume of traffic and then start scaling costs after that. If you do decide to roll your own, then on the client side [RestKit](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit) is definitely a good place to start as a client side framework onto a REST based service API.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a custom class that uses AFNetworking for the network requests.  I have used it with both PHP and .NET based web-services.  As the requests use POST parameters, it is really flexible.

Here is the class:

Interface File:

```
/*
 NetworkClient.h

 Created by LJ Wilson on 2/3/12.
 Copyright (c) 2012 LJ Wilson. All rights reserved.
 License:

 Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy of this software 
 and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal in the Software without restriction, 
 including without limitation the rights to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, 
 sublicense, and/or sell copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is 
 furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:

 The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all copies or 
 substantial portions of the Software.

 THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT 
 NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND 
 NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, 
 DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, OUT 
 OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.
 */

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

extern NSString * const APIKey;

@interface NetworkClient : NSObject

+(void)processURLRequestWithURL:(NSString *)url 
                      andParams:(NSDictionary *)params 
                          block:(void (^)(id obj))block;

+(void)processURLRequestWithURL:(NSString *)url 
                      andParams:(NSDictionary *)params 
                    syncRequest:(BOOL)syncRequest
                          block:(void (^)(id obj))block;

+(void)processURLRequestWithURL:(NSString *)url 
                      andParams:(NSDictionary *)params 
                    syncRequest:(BOOL)syncRequest
             alertUserOnFailure:(BOOL)alertUserOnFailure
                          block:(void (^)(id obj))block;

+(void)handleNetworkErrorWithError:(NSError *)error;

+(void)handleNoAccessWithReason:(NSString *)reason;

@end
```

Implementation File:

```
/*
 NetworkClient.m

 Created by LJ Wilson on 2/3/12.
 Copyright (c) 2012 LJ Wilson. All rights reserved.
 License:

 Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy of this software 
 and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal in the Software without restriction, 
 including without limitation the rights to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, 
 sublicense, and/or sell copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is 
 furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:

 The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all copies or 
 substantial portions of the Software.

 THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT 
 NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND 
 NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, 
 DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, OUT 
 OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.
 */

#import "NetworkClient.h"
#import "AFHTTPClient.h"
#import "AFHTTPRequestOperation.h"
#import "SBJson.h"

NSString * const APIKey = @"APIKEY IF SO DESIRED (ADDS SECURITY)";

@implementation NetworkClient

+(void)processURLRequestWithURL:(NSString *)url 
                      andParams:(NSDictionary *)params 
                          block:(void (^)(id obj))block {

    [self processURLRequestWithURL:url andParams:params syncRequest:NO alertUserOnFailure:NO block:^(id obj) {
        block(obj);
    }];
}

+(void)processURLRequestWithURL:(NSString *)url 
                      andParams:(NSDictionary *)params 
                    syncRequest:(BOOL)syncRequest
                          block:(void (^)(id obj))block {
    [self processURLRequestWithURL:url andParams:params syncRequest:syncRequest alertUserOnFailure:NO block:^(id obj) {
        block(obj);
    }];
}


+(void)processURLRequestWithURL:(NSString *)url 
                      andParams:(NSDictionary *)params 
                    syncRequest:(BOOL)syncRequest
             alertUserOnFailure:(BOOL)alertUserOnFailure
                          block:(void (^)(id obj))block {

    // Default url goes here, pass in a nil to use it
    if (url == nil) {
        url = @"DEFAULT URL HERE";
    }

    NSMutableDictionary *newParams = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:params];
    [newParams setValue:APIKey forKey:@"APIKey"];

    NSURL *requestURL;
    AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:requestURL];

    NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [httpClient requestWithMethod:@"POST" path:url parameters:newParams];

    __block NSString *responseString = @"";

    AFHTTPRequestOperation *_operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest];
    __weak AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = _operation;

    [operation  setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        responseString = [operation responseString];

        id retObj = [responseString JSONValue];

        // Check for invalid response (No Access)
        if ([retObj isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
            if ([[(NSDictionary *)retObj valueForKey:@"Message"] isEqualToString:@"No Access"]) {
                block(nil);
                [self handleNoAccessWithReason:[(NSDictionary *)retObj valueForKey:@"Reason"]];
            }
        } else if ([retObj isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
            if ([(NSArray *)retObj count] > 0) {
                NSDictionary *dict = [(NSArray *)retObj objectAtIndex:0];
                if ([[dict valueForKey:@"Message"] isEqualToString:@"No Access"]) {
                    block(nil);
                    [self handleNoAccessWithReason:[(NSDictionary *)retObj valueForKey:@"Reason"]];
                }
            }
        }
        block(retObj);
    } 
                                      failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                                          NSLog(@"Failed with error = %@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"[Error]:%@",error]);
                                          block(nil);
                                          if (alertUserOnFailure) {
                                              // Let the user know something went wrong
                                              [self handleNetworkErrorWithError:operation.error];
                                          }

                                      }];

    [operation start];

    if (syncRequest) {
        // Process the request syncronously
        [operation waitUntilFinished];
    } 


}


+(void)handleNetworkErrorWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSString *errorString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"[Error]:%@",error];

    // Standard UIAlert Syntax
    UIAlertView *myAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] 
                            initWithTitle:@"Connection Error" 
                            message:errorString 
                            delegate:nil 
                            cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                            otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

    [myAlert show];

}

+(void)handleNoAccessWithReason:(NSString *)reason {
    // Standard UIAlert Syntax
    UIAlertView *myAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] 
                            initWithTitle:@"No Access" 
                            message:reason 
                            delegate:nil 
                            cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                            otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

    [myAlert show];

}


@end
```

An example call would be something like:

```
NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                            @"GetMeetingRooms", @"Command",
                            nil];

    [NetworkClient processURLRequestWithURL:nil andParams:params block:^(id obj) {
        // Check to make sure we got back a response message (NSArray of NSDictionaries in JSON format
        if ([obj isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
            NSArray *response = (NSArray *)obj;
            // So dome work here with the response here
        }
    }];
```

If you have any questions, let me know.